# Set Imageview as wallpaper with a Button

Tags: android, imageview, wallpaper

I have a problem with my code, I want to set an image from an `ImageView` as the wallpaper, I have a gallery and when I press an image from there the `ImageView` changes, so I don't know where to put the code for `onClick` to my button.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    final Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.a_compressed, R.drawable.b_compressed,
            R.drawable.c_compressed, R.drawable.d_compressed,
           };
    final Integer[] mFullSizeIds = {
            R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
           };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gallery galeria = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        galeria.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        galeria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                ImageView laimagen = (ImageView) findViewById(wallpaper);
                laimagen.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
            }
        });
    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(MainActivity inicio) {
            mContext = inicio;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
             return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
             return mFullSizeIds[position];
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(180, 170));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            return imageView;

        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
private void onClick() {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),mFullSizeIds[position]);

    try {
        getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#222222"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView android:id="@id/wallpaper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/a" />

<Gallery android:id="@id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@id/set"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SetWallpaper"
    android:background="@color/Esmeralda"
    android:textColor="@color/Clouds"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whts the use of button here? you simply change the image background when you click on an item in gallery.If i misunderstood you,please correct me

Comment: when i press a image from the gallery, this image shows in the imageview, I do it to see the image in a larger size and the user can see if you like it or not to use wallpaper, once the user image seems fine, pressed a button to perform this action

Comment: okay the sequence of execution is
first you will select an image from gallery by clicking on any of them
secondally the selected image is displayed in an ImageView having id wallpaper and then finally user has the option to set it as wallpaper by clicking the button set. am i right??

Comment: Yes, in theory that's how the app should work, but i don't know how and where put te code for the button

Comment: okay one more doubt, by clicking set button you want to set the image as your mobile wallpaper or want to show simply somewhere in your app?? and your images showing are static only??

Comment: Yes, i wanna set the images as mobile wallpaper, and yes all the images are static

Comment: see the answer i have posted, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should take an int variable which specifies basically the index of drawableIds present in your mFullSizeIds[] and intialise it to -1 intitially like this

```
private int index=-1;
```

and in your  galeria.setOnItemClickListener(), assign the position to your index variable like this.

```
 galeria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            index=position;
            laimagen.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
        }
    });
```

and then in your Button click, do something like this

```
private void onClick() {

  try {
       WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity .this); 
       Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mFullSizeIds[index]);// here index is position of selected drawable in your mFullSizeIds[] that you have set in galeria.setOnItemClickListener()
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

your onCreate() will look like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView laimagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
    Gallery galeria = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    galeria.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    galeria.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
              index=position;
              laimagen.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
        }
    });
    Button setButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
     setButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works :D, thank you very much my friend, i really appreciated your help.  I will comment for future, on the code that you put for the onCreate() is missing index=position;  after --> public void onItemClick(AdapterView.... it's all. :D

Comment: hehe.. sorry for that just forgot to include that, thanks I have just updated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the sample code for wallpaper

```
public class WallpaperMainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());

/** A list containing the resource identifiers for all of our selectable backgrounds */
private static final List<Integer> backgrounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/** The total number of backgrounds in the list */
private static final int TOTAL_IMAGES;
/** Instantiate the list statically, so this will be done once on app load, also 
  calculate the total number of backgrounds */
static {
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background1);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background2);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background3);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background4);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background5);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background6);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background7);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background8);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background9);
    backgrounds.add(R.drawable.background10);

    // We -1 as lists are zero indexed (0-2 is a size of 3) - we'll mke use of this to 
   implement a browsing loop
    TOTAL_IMAGES = (backgrounds.size() - 1);
  }
/** the state of what wallpaper is currently being previewed */
private int currentPosition = 0;
/** our image wallpaper preview */
private ImageView backgroundPreview;
/** A helper class that will do the heavy work of decoding images and actually setting 
the wallpaper */
private HeavyLifter chuckNorris;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper_main);
    backgroundPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundPreview);
    backgroundPreview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {

            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Set the default image to be shown to start with
    changePreviewImage(currentPosition);
    // Load are heavy lifter (goes and does work on another thread), to get a response 
    after the lifters thread
    // has finished we pass in a Handler that will be notified when it completes
    chuckNorris = new HeavyLifter(this, chuckFinishedHandler);

}

/**
 * Called from XML when the previous button is pressed
 * Decrement the current state position
 * If the position is now less than 0 loop round and show the last image (the array size)
 * @param v
 */
public void gotoPreviousImage(View v) {
    int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
    positionToMoveTo--;
    if(positionToMoveTo < 0){
        positionToMoveTo = TOTAL_IMAGES;
    }
    changePreviewImage(positionToMoveTo);
}

/**
 * Called from XML when the set wallpaper button is pressed
 * Thie retrieves the id of the current image from our list
 * It then asks chuck to set it as a wallpaper!
 * The chuckHandler will be called when this operation is complete
 * @param v
 */
public void setAsWallpaper(View v) {

    int resourceId = backgrounds.get(currentPosition);
    chuckNorris.setResourceAsWallpaper(resourceId);

    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(WallpaperMainActivity.this);
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcheralert);
    ab.setTitle("Image set as Background....");
   ab.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
   } );

   ab.show();


}

/**
 * Called from XML when the next button is pressed
 * Increment the current state position
 * If the position is now greater than are array size loop round and show the first image again
 * @param v
 */
public void gotoNextImage(View v) {
    int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
    positionToMoveTo++;
    if(currentPosition == TOTAL_IMAGES){
        positionToMoveTo = 0;
    } 

    changePreviewImage(positionToMoveTo);
}

/**
 * Change the currently showing image on the screen
 * This is quite an expensive operation as each time the system
 * has to decode the image from our resources - alternatives are possible (a list of drawables created at app start)
 * @param pos the position in {@link MainActivity#backgrounds} to select the image from
 */
public void changePreviewImage(int pos) {
    currentPosition = pos;
    backgroundPreview.setImageResource(backgrounds.get(pos));
    Log.d("Main", "Current position: "+pos);
}

/**
 * This is the handler that is notified when are HeavyLifter is finished doing an operation
 */
private Handler chuckFinishedHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS:
            break;
        case FAIL:
            Toast.makeText(WallpaperMainActivity.this, "Uh oh, can't do that right now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
   class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
                    positionToMoveTo--;
                    if(positionToMoveTo < 0){
                        positionToMoveTo = TOTAL_IMAGES;
                    }
                    changePreviewImage(positionToMoveTo);
                    return true;
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    // left to right swipe
                    int positionToMoveTo = currentPosition;
                    positionToMoveTo++;
                    if(currentPosition == TOTAL_IMAGES){
                        positionToMoveTo = 0;
                    } 

                    changePreviewImage(positionToMoveTo);
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Create Another  new class

```
 public class HeavyLifter {

 public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
 public static final int FAIL = 1;

 private final Context context;
 private final Handler callback;
 private WallpaperManager manager;

 /**
 * Setup the HeavyLifter
 * @param context the context we are running in - typically an activity
 * @param callback the handler you want to be notified when we finish doing an operation
 */
  public HeavyLifter(Context context, Handler callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.manager = (WallpaperManager)  
     context.getSystemService(Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
 }

  /**
 * Takes a resource id of a file within our /res/drawable/ folder<br/>
 * It then spawns a new thread to do its work on<br/>
 * The reource is decoded and converted to a byte array<br/>
 * This array is passed to the system which can use it to set the phones wallpaper<br/>
 * Upon completion the callback handler is sent a message with eith {@link 
  HeavyLifter#SUCCESS} or {@link HeavyLifter#FAIL}
 * 
 * @param resourceId id of a file within our /res/drawable/ folder
 */
 public void setResourceAsWallpaper(final int resourceId) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                manager.setBitmap(getImage(resourceId));
                callback.sendEmptyMessage(SUCCESS);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", "Cant set wallpaper");
                callback.sendEmptyMessage(FAIL);
            }
        }
    }.start();
  }

  /**
 * Decodes a resource into a bitmap, here it uses the convenience method 
'BitmapFactory.decodeResource', but you can decode
 * using alternatives these will give you more control over the size and quality of the 
 resource.
 * You may need certain size resources within each of your /hdpi/ /mdpi/ /ldpi/ folders
  in order
 * to have the quality and look you want on each different phone.
 */
private Bitmap getImage(int resourceId) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, 
null);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 
manager.getDesiredMinimumWidth(), manager.getDesiredMinimumHeight(), true);
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    return scaledBitmap;
 }
}
```

add this to your manifest

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

and

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciated your answere  but i already solve the problem.